# Is there any way to create Database on cPanel using PHP

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying with Xmlapi but firstly I got nothing and after debugging the code I got the error " HTTP error 404 ". How can I get out of this. I am currently using this API in codeigniter.

Below is my Code:-

```
require("xmlapi.php"); 
$xmlapi = new xmlapi("domain");   
$xmlapi->set_port( 2083 );   
$xmlapi->password_auth($opts['user'],$opts['pass']);    
$xmlapi->set_debug(0);
$cpaneluser=$opts['user'];
$databasename="dbName";
$databaseuser="dbUser";
$databasepass='dbPassword';

$createdb = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adddb", array($databasename));   

$usr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduser", array($databaseuser, $databasepass));   

$addusr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduserdb", array("".$cpaneluser."_".$databasename."", "".$cpaneluser."_".$databaseuser."", 'all'));
```

Comment: you need to share code to help you

Comment: A `404` status code would indicate the resource is not located where it should be. I'm not familiar with `Xmlapi`. The title of the question seems unrelated.

Comment: I have shared the code.